# How to get the last record in a output by group?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query that I want to output by group.
Here is what I have right now I made a 
https://jsfiddle.net/nbqqp0cb/2/

```
 "dataset": [
   <cfoutput query="all_dates" group="Month_new">
                  {

                        "seriesname": "#all_dates.Month_new#",

                    "data": [
                     <cfoutput>
                      <CFIF all_dates.CurrentRow EQ all_dates.RecordCount> 
                          {

                           "value": "#sum_total#"
                          } 

                      <br>
                     <cfelse>
                           {

                            "value": "#sum_total#"

                          }, <br>
                      </cfif>
                       </cfoutput>

                   ]
                    },<br>


                        </cfoutput>
```

The problem is the last comma in each group. I got it to work for the last record, but even the last record has a comma in the end which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition `<CFIF all_dates.CurrentRow EQ all_dates.RecordCount>` is checking the `CurrentRow` against the entire `RecordCount` from the query. You need to check against each group's count instead. Since you don't have a group count (I assume) in your query result set then you need to check for it in a different way. This may not be the most elegant approach but it should work.

First above this code initialize a new variable:

```
<cfset previous_month = "" >
```

Then modify your code as follows (this is pseudo-code and has not been tested):

```
"dataset": [
<cfoutput query="all_dates" group="Month_new">
    {
        "seriesname": "#all_dates.Month_new#",
        "data": [
        <cfoutput>
            <cfif all_dates.CurrentRow GT 1>
                <cfif previous_month EQ all_dates.Month_new and all_dates.CurrentRow LT all_dates.RecordCount> 
                    , <br>
                <cfelse>
                    <br>
                </cfif>
            </cfif>
            {
                "value": "#sum_total#"
            }
            <cfset previous_month = all_dates.Month_new>
        </cfoutput>
        ]
    }
    <cfif all_dates.CurrentRow LT all_dates.RecordCount>,</cfif>
    <br>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: yes it work good, only problem im getting into is the last } , since the last } should not have a , in the end

Comment: you will need to add a similar condition/logic to the outer loop as well. I have added the code to my answer.

Comment: Might also be able to [build a list/array of value strings first](http://trycf.com/gist/a6fdde2dbd28fed824eb0fd1d792da9b/acf2016?theme=monokai) and avoid the whole comma issue? That said, @anatp_123 - do you really have to build JSON strings manually?

Comment: @leigh no i dont need to, im new to using json

Comment: @anatp_123 - Depending on what you are building, you might want to take a look at the serialize/DeserializeJSON functions, which convert standard CF objects (arrays and structs) to/from JSON format. They do have some "quirks", but a big advantage over building JSON strings by hand is they auto escape reserved characters.